# How to do bundle install using specific rvm gemset from git hook post-receive?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, rvm, bundler

So, I'm trying to implement a heroku-like deployment without using capistrano.
To check and install gems I'm trying to use git hook and put the following commands in /hooks/post-receive:

```
bundle check || bundle install
```

But when I run `git push` I get:

```
remote: hooks/post-receive: line 20: bundle: command not found.
```

I understand that a hook probably launches commands from the wrong environment and somehow I have to switch rvm environment from hook. I tried to use rvm use 1.8.7@rails3 in post-receive but it didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: How RVM is installed on the target system? Globally or only for a single user? Has the git system user access to rvm (is also in the rvm group)? Maybe you have to source the rvm environment first to the post-receive hook (because I think, the hooks won't create a shell session with the right sources/settings).

Comment: I think that your question is related with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23979647/bundle-install-not-running-from-my-post-update-hook

Answer (score 7):

You might just have to make sure you source the user's environment at the top of the hook, for example:

```
$ source $HOME/.bash_profile # single user RVM setup
$ source /etc/profile        # multi user RVM setup
```

Comment: I was having the exact same problem (however I am not using RVM, I have just one Ruby version installed). The solution you suggested did not work for me, but it got me to figure out the problem was with the PATH. Thanks for that! What worked for me was including Ruby's bin folder to the path at the beginning of the post-receive hook (e.g. `PATH=$PATH:/home/deploy/ruby_2.1.1/bin`).