# bundle install not running from my post-update hook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, git, bash

I've setup a post-update hook for my project. I have a bare repository (/var/git/myproject) which I push to, and a live repository (/var/www/myproject) where my app is running. I also included `bundle install` and `bundle exec rake db:migrate` to install gems and update db.

Below is my post-update hook

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Pulling changes into Live..."
cd /var/www/myproject || exit
unset GIT_DIR
git pull origin master

# check if ruby app
if [ -f /var/www/myproject/Gemfile ];
then
  echo "  Ruby app detected..."
  bundle install --without development test
  bundle exec rake db:migrate # migrate database
fi

exec git-update-server-info
```

When I push my changes though I get the following message (notice the "bundle command not found" error):

```
martyn@localhost:~/www/myproject$ git push -u origin master
martyn@192.168.0.100's password: 
Counting objects: 832, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (783/783), done.
Writing objects: 100% (832/832), 487.70 KiB, done.
Total 832 (delta 434), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Pulling changes into Live...
remote: From /var/git/myproject
remote:  * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
remote: Ruby app detected...
remote: hooks/post-update: line 13: bundle: command not found
remote: hooks/post-update: line 14: bundle: command not found
To 192.168.24.100:/var/git/myproject.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
```

Why is bundle not running? I `cd` to the live app directory in the script. When I'm in terminal myself and I `cd` to the live directory and run `bundle install` it works so bundle is there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your hook shell ins't the same than the one you logged in (and which has the proper `PATH`)

You can try using at the beginning your your hook script:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
```

(See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12347966/6309)

> The `-l` parameter executes the command in a login shell, which means that it inherits your path and other settings from your shell profile.

)

Or you can make sure your script gets the same environment than your current session, by adding in the first lines of your hook:

```
$ source $HOME/.bash_profile # single user RVM setup
$ source /etc/profile        # multi user RVM setup
```

Or (final alternative) you can add (before calling `bundle`) (for a single-user rvm installation)

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```